# Pass null values to SVG path (using d3.js) to suppress missing data

Tags: path, svg, flot, d3.js

Using jQuery Flot, I can pass a `null` value to the plotting mechanism so it just won't draw anything on the plot. See how the missing records are suppressed:

[image]

I'm looking to move to `d3js`, so that I can have deeper low level control of the graphics using SVG. However, I have yet to find out how to do that same process of suppressing missing records. The image below is an attempt to do this, using a value of `0` instead of `null` (where the `d3` package breaks down). Here is some code to give you an idea of how I produced the graph below:

```js
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) {
       var date = new Date(d[0]);
       return x(date);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
       var height = d[1]; 
       if (no_record_exists) {
           return y(0);
       }
       return y(height) + 0.5;
    });
```

[image]

I looked up the SVG `path` element at the Mozilla Developer Network, and I found out that there is a MoveTo command, `M x y`, that only moves the "pen" to some point without drawing anything. Has this been implemented in the `d3js` package, so that I won't have to create several `path` elements every time I encounter a missing record?

Comment: Note that using MoveTo would be great for having gaps in a simple (stroke-only) line, but would not work will with the green fill you show above. For that, you need distinct shapes or superfluous path commands to drop down to the baseline, come over the correct amount, and come back up again.

Comment: Love the graphs, but see also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259444/drawing-non-continuous-lines-with-d3

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The `defined` function of `d3.svg.line()` is the way to do this

Let's say we want to include a break in the chart if y is null:

```
line.defined(function(d) { return d.y!=null; })
```

Answer (score 18):

Use [line.defined](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#line_defined) or [area.defined](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#area_defined), and see the [Area with Missing Data](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090) example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look this up. Actually I just raised an issue at Github regarding this :) Not really sure how to move forward with it though  :( https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/583

Comment: What's d3.split?  there's nothing on that page.  Should probably also update your response, since http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259444/drawing-non-continuous-lines-with-d3 now shows how to do it.