# Drawing non-continuous lines with d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3.js to make a simple line graph. I want to know if there's a way to create "holes" in the graph, that is, if the line can be interrupted or cut when there is no data available.

I'm looking into either delete the places I don't need from the domain, or setting the line weight to 0 in specific segments, but I can't find a way to do either of these.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The D3 [line](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line) generator has a built in function to do just this, [line.defined](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_defined).  You can use this function to control where your line is defined and where it is not (like where you have missing data.)  If you wanted to make your line undefined whenever the second value in the point array is a javascript NaN value, you could say:

```
line.defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d[1]); });
```

[Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090) is a good example of this in action.

Comment: Your example will not work (as intended) because if `d` is `null` the function would either never be called or can not determine where the undefined position is (on the x axis e.g.). In the block-code the code used is `return d.y != null`.

Comment: Thanks @Rouby.  I've updated the answer with the current example from the API docs.

Comment: It works only if the data has values with undefined type. What if the key is discrete but each key has a value ?