# How split line in D3.js when missing data

Tags: d3.js

My data source can be missing data for example:

7/1/13  1

7/2/13  2

7/3/13  3

7/4/13  4

7/5/13  5

7/8/13  8

7/9/13  9
......

When I use d3.svg.line().x(X).y(Y1) where X and Y are my accessor functions. It will draw a continuous line. I was wondering how can split this up into two different lines, such that missing days can be easily seen.

I mean I should get a line for 1 to 5 and then a line for 8 to 9. No connection between 5 to 8.

Comment: D3 doesn't do this by default. You'll have to draw several lines or implement a custom line generator.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing non-continuous lines with d3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259444/drawing-non-continuous-lines-with-d3)

Comment: @Josh: It is not a duplicate as I don't have nulls in the data set. Its completely missing. No data at all.

Comment: maybe that's just what you need to do, insert the null values..

Comment: Yes, that's what I finally ended up doing. I added null values for missing dates in my JS code.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to specify if data is defined, at least there is in the current version of d3:

```
d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d){return d.y != null && d.y != undefined})
```

Or with areas:

```
d3.svg.area()
    .defined(function(d){return d.y != null && d.y != undefined})
```

This works wonders for me.

When data is not defined, a sharp cliff will appear.
Check this out for an example:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090

Comment: What's the difference between the two code-blocks? Did you mean `d3.svg.line()` in the first?

Comment: This won't solve the problem if the data is structured as in the question. The issue is .defined() is only called for elements exist in the array and can be identified. When the missing elements aren't represented in the data array, .defined() won't help.