# d3.js: Highlight or hide part of line in line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js, linechart

Does anyone know if it is possible to highlight (or hide) just a part of a line in a d3 line chart? So far the only solution I've come up with is to create an extra, small line on top of the other line, but this feels a bit messy.

Comment: It'll be helpful to see some code. Preferably JSFiddle

Comment: Rather than creating an extra line on top of it. Why don't u split the existing line into parts and then just set the required part's `visibility` to `hidden`.

Comment: I'll try that. Will also look at these:
- [split line in D3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17757551/how-split-line-in-d3-js-when-missing-data)
- [drawing non-continuous lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259444/drawing-non-continuous-lines-with-d3)