# breaking a line with d3/linechart

Tags: r, d3.js, linechart, rcharts

I'm trying to replicate the following graph, obtained with `R`'s `ggplot2`, with the `rCharts/d3` library (the dataframe df is defined further down):

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Year, y = value, 
    group = interaction(variable,Category), 
    colour = variable, shape = variable)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

I have not been able to group by the interaction of the variables, as with the `ggplot` example:

```
nPlot(data = df, value ~ Year, 
    group = 'variable', 
    type = 'lineChart')
```

[image]

Unfortunately the last and first points of the two series are connected (between the years 1870 and 2010), which is undesirable of course. Replacing `group = 'variable'`  with something like `group = interaction(df$variable, df$Category)` didn't give anything useful.

**Any ideas how to *not* connect the points across the two series?**

There is a related *SO* question here [Drawing non-continuous lines with d3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259444/drawing-non-continuous-lines-with-d3) with what looks like a very promising answer. But coming from `rCharts` and not being familiar with `d3` I have not been able to adapt the solution proposed there to my situation.

I tried to adapt the code found here http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3035090, on which the *SO* answer is based, but I'm not sufficiently familiar with `d3` and `rCharts` to make it work. What I tried to do was to add an `NaN` data point and not display the `NaN`, which is what I understand is done in the example above. I have not been successful, but here is my attempt anyhow:

```
df2 <- subset(df, Year %in% 1870)
df2$Year <- 1869  # add non-numeric entry at 1869 
                  # break the interpolation between 1870 and 2010?
df2$value <- NaN
df <- rbind(df, df2)
n <- nPlot(data = df, value ~ Year, group = 'variable', type = 'lineChart')
n$setTemplate(afterScript = 
  '<style>  # code snippet copied from Mike Bostock's example
  var line = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return !isNaN(d.dataValue); })
  </style>')
n
```

I've tried other variants without success. I also tried to edit the html directly, but failed too.

Here is the dataframe to replicate the graphs:

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(1870, 1880, 1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 
1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 1870, 1880, 1890, 
1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 
2010, 1870, 1880, 1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 
1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 1870, 1880, 1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 
1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010, 1870, 1880, 
1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 
2000, 2010, 1870, 1880, 1890, 1900, 1910, 1920, 1930, 1940, 1950, 
1960, 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010), Category = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("National capital", 
"Private capital", "Public capital"), class = "factor"), variable = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("United States", 
"Germany", "France", "United Kingdom", "Europe"), class = "factor"), 
    value = c(7.1, 6.9, 6.3, 6.5, 6.4, 3.5, 3.8, 2.9, 2.3, 3, 
    3.1, 3.5, 3.6, 3.9, 4.1, 0.7, 0.5, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 1, 0.7, 
    0.2, 0.7, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.4, 0.1, 0, 7.2, 7, 7, 7, 6.7, 
    2.9, 3.8, 2.8, 2.8, 3.2, 3.6, 3.7, 3.7, 5, 6.1, 0.2, -0.4, 
    -0.3, -0.3, -0.3, -0.4, 0.4, -0.3, 0.6, 0.4, 0.5, 0.4, 0.3, 
    0.3, 0.3, 6.7, 6.8, 6.8, 6.8, 6.8, 2.9, 3.6, 2.6, 2.3, 2.8, 
    3.3, 4, 4.6, 4.9, 5.2, -0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.3, 0.1, -1.5, -1.5, 
    -1.4, -0.8, -0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Year", 
"Category", "variable", "value"), row.names = c(NA, -90L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creating a new column in your dataframe with the interaction and then grouping on that column in nPlot, instead of doing the interaction in the nPlot, seems to do the trick:

```
df$interaction=interaction(df$variable,df$Category)
nPlot(data = df, value ~ Year, 
  group = 'interaction', 
  type = 'lineChart')
```

You might have to change the legend

Comment: Thanks NicE! I missed the notification, so it took me a couple of days to notice your answer, sorry about that!

Comment: I found that using the ``sep`` option of ``interaction`()` gave me acceptable names for the legend, i.e. ``df$interaction <- interaction(df$variable, df$Category, sep = " ")``