# d3 define lines depending on days difference between data dates

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I've got a bunch of datas which are containing dates, the charts are drawn with dots(circles) connected with each other and everything is fine. Now i want to connect only the dots which dates are separated by maximum 7 days (<=7).

I found out that there is a build in `defined`function and this is probably what i have to use.

I want to achieve [this](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0533f44f2cfabecc5e3a).

In the example above the datas where shouldn't be a line is set as null, so i have to do it a little different.

I also saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15259444/drawing-non-continuous-lines-with-d3) but this isn't what i need.

Here is what i have so far (i think i'm on the right track but i'm missing something):

```
let valueline = d3.line()
  .defined(function(d) {
    let nextDate = (resources[d.axis].samples[d.index + 1]) ? resources[d.axis].samples[d.index + 1].date.getTime() : undefined,
        previousDate = (resources[d.axis].samples[d.index - 1]) ? resources[d.axis].samples[d.index - 1].date.getTime() : undefined,
        currentDate = d.date.getTime(),

        //most relevant code from here

        differenceNext = Math.floor((nextDate - currentDate) / 86400000),
        differencePrevious = Math.floor((currentDate - previousDate) / 86400000);

    if(differencePrevious <= 7 || isNaN(differencePrevious)){ //or use differenceNext
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  })
  .//some more line callbacks (x, y)
```

So i tried multiple combinations using `differencePrevious` or `differenceNext`  and the results are different. sometimes the circles are connected correctly and sometimes not.

Do both line indexes which should be connected have to get `true`returned from the `defined` `callback`?

[docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape/blob/master/README.md#line_defined)

Really need help on this and would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of a workaround would be to modify your data by adding `null` values between data points that are further than 7 days apart and then use the same code for line generation as in the [example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/0533f44f2cfabecc5e3a). I wrote a function that can do this for you.

```
    function insertNulls(list, maxBreak, acc){
      var listCopy = list.slice() // To return a new list 
      listCopy.map((d,i,arr)=> acc(d) - acc(arr[i-1]) > maxBreak ? i : false)
        .filter(d => d)
        .reverse()
        .forEach(d => listCopy.splice(d,0,null)) //insert nulls
      return listCopy      
    }

    var foo = [1,2,3,5,6,15,17,25];  
    console.log(insertNulls(foo,7,function(d){return d}));
    //[1, 2, 3, 5, 6, null, 15, 17, null, 25]
```

Then use this function when binding data and leave the original data unchanged. You might need to change the accessor function.

```
   var DAY_IN_MS = 86400000;
   ... 

   .data(insertNulls(yourData,7,function(d){return d.date.getTime()/DAY_IN_MS})
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, seems to be the way to do it, but i still don't get how and where i have to implement it in my code. here is a reduced example of what i'm doing, could you maybe take little bit of your time again to show me where i have to put it please? https://jsfiddle.net/rzxa19kq/54/

Comment: ok i think i'm getting nearer, just need to get rid of this additional circle in the top left https://jsfiddle.net/rzxa19kq/56/ the i'll accept the answer

Comment: I am glad you made it!