# How do I get d3 to treat missing values as null instead of zero?

Tags: d3.js

[JSBin of my example with code](http://jsbin.com/zuwogo/1/edit)

I have a line chart of two variables on separate axes:

[image]

The .csv file has missing values at the beginning and end for the blue series ('close'):

```
date,open,close
1-May-89,161,
1-May-90,170,
1-May-91,137,
1-May-92,144,91.9
1-May-93,91,91.8

(...)

1-May-11,12,75.7
1-May-12,7,68.2
1-May-13,15,
```

The missing value at the end is handled properly (the line is truncated), but the first three are treated as zero values. How can I have the blue, 'close' series start at 1992?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Pass null values to SVG path (using d3.js) to suppress missing data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9580003/pass-null-values-to-svg-path-using-d3-js-to-suppress-missing-data)

Answer (score 5):

Fixed by using @mccannf's suggestion, I changed one block to:

```
var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .defined(function(d) { return d.close != 0; }) // added this line
    .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
    .y(function(d) { return y0(d.close); });
```

For some reason, the following didn't work, even though it's what's cited in the example:

```
.defined(function(d) { return d.close != null; })
```

Comment: your nulls were being converted to zero in this section: `d.close = +d.close;` so that's why the comparison to null failed.